# suddenly cannot read file of type

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing a data acquisition (via Bluetooth) application (Document Based) that can SAVE acquired data and later OPEN the data for study and analysis.  All was well when suddenly an attempt to OPEN a previously SAVEd file gets a panel:

The document "xxxxx.bsd" could not
be opened. BalanceDoc cannot open files
in the "BalanceData" format.

- What changes were made to induce this behavior are unknown.
- "BalanceData" is the correct type and is confirmed to be in the filesystem and plist.
- I have slaved over the Info.plist to no avail.
- The .bsd file extension seems to be working O.K. (when not in the plist, files are not selectable.)
- In the file menu, the OPEN menu item is Not enabled; (however OPEN RECENT is enabled).
- The application can still *SAVE AS* with no problem.
- I created a fresh, barebones Document Based application to experiment with: it works O.K. (With a pretty 'barebones' Info.plist)

I would appreciate suggestions on additional experiments.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your loading code and see where it fails? Or post some relevant code and data here; Most users here don't have crystal balls to debug problems remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed anything in the data model? If so, this will certainly cause issues with your saved files which were saved with a different data model.

If this is happening even with NEW files you create then try and open, have you:

1) Enabled Sandboxing?

2) have you got customised both:

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError;
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError;
```

.. or are you using the ones which are already in place? Either way, can you paste the code from both of those?

3) Is there anything in 'Console' which comes up with a little more information that the error you provided?